# Convert image format from .bmp to other image formats in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image-manipulation

How do you convert a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` image to another type of image? I tried CType, which failed, since I do not know the type for .png or .jpg. I cannot find it anywhere on google either.

What is the most efficient method to do this while keeping the quality of the image as high as possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system.Drawing.Bitmap class can handle opening and saving any kind of [bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) image, including JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP, and others.

To save an already opened file as a different format you can use the save method as so

```
MyImage.Save("ImageName.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The class name of Bitmp refers more specifically to the general concept of storing a picture as a series of coloured pixels rather then the actual format of BMP, which is one possible way to store the representation of the pixels that make up an image.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Drawing.Bitmap.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) method.  I recommend saving as PNG - it's lossless and achieves reasonable compression.  See the [Imaging.ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx) enum - this is how you specify the image type you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to convert an image type without saving to a file in VB.NET
You might also be able to port this into C#, but I haven't tested that.

```
Public Function ConvertImageType(Image As Bitmap, Format As 
    Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As Byte()
        'Declare a new memory stream to write to
        Dim SaveStream As New IO.MemoryStream
        'Save the bitmap/image to the memory stream in the desired format
        Image.Save(SaveStream, Format)
        'Extract the file bytes from the memory stream
        Dim ConvertedImageBytes() As Byte = SaveStream.ToArray
        'Return bytes to caller
        Return ConvertedImageBytes
    End Function
```

This method can convert a Bitmap/Image type to the following formats: Jpeg, Png, Bmp, Ico, Gif, Emf, Exif, Tiff and Wmf.